# Selenium Webdriver: NameError name 'firefox' is not defined

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write this code using Selenium and Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html')

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

email = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email.send_keys('user@gmail.com')

passwd = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]')
passwd.send_keys('123456')
```

But I don't understand why this error occured, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are making a an instance of the webdriver.Firefox() object and calling it browser

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Later on in your code, you try to find an element by xpath using a varible called firefox

```
email = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
```

The problem is that that firefox was never actually created, I think what you meant to do is

```
email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
```

Comment: SO MUCH THANK YOU, I knew this, but I don't tried "browser.find", only "driver.find" and didn't correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable `browser` as a webdriver object. You then attempt to use `firefox` as a webdriver object, but you never defined the variable `firefox`. This is one way to solve your problem. You're better off calling the variable `browser`, rather than `firefox`, because then you can just change the browser type in your first line of code and the code will not be confusing.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://demo.guru99.com/test/login.html')

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email.send_keys('user@gmail.com')

passwd = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]')
passwd.send_keys('123456')
```

Comment: SO MUCH THANK YOU, I knew this, but I don't tried "browser.find", only "driver.find" and didn't correct. Thank you

Comment: You need to tick and upvote the answer if it is correct so that others who face similar problem in future can take a reference.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to stack overflow! When you get an answer that solves your problem, upvote all that were helpful, and then click Accept on the one that best solved your problem.